# Why this SPARQL query don't work into Prolog?

Tags: prolog, sparql, semantic-web

I am trying to integrate SPARQL queries into Prolog program (I am using SWI-Prolog)

To test it I am doing the following operations:

1. Into SWI-Prolog shell I execute this command: **use_module(library(semweb/sparql_client)).** that load the sparql client library
2. Then, in the SWI-Prolog shell, I execute the following SPARQL query:

   ?- sparql_query('select count(*) where { ?person a http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Person .?person http://it.dbpedia.org/property/nome ?name.filter regex(?name,"Leonardo"). }', Row, [ host('dbpedia.org'), path('/sparql/')]).
   Row = row(literal(type('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer', '0'))).

I don't know well SPARQL but I think that this is pretty simple and that work in this way:

This query ask about the instances number of objects that are considered personal names on a RDF ontology called dbpedia, passing the input parameter "Leonardo".

As you can see the problem seems that don't find any instance of this type (I have tried also with others personal name)

Why? What are am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your query does not return what you want it to return.  You can use SPARQL interactively with the [DBpedia SPARQL endpoint](http://dbpedia.org/sparql).  I suggest that you use that to debug your query and make sure it returns what you would like first, and then copy it into your Prolog program.  You can build it up in pieces to make sure it's giving suitable results.  For instance, start with something like the following:

```
select * where {
  ?person a <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Person> .
}
LIMIT 10
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select+%2a+where+%7B%0D%0A++%3Fperson+a+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2FPerson%3E+.%0D%0A%7D%0D%0ALIMIT+10&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=0&debug=on)

Then expand it piece by piece:

```
select * where {
  ?person a <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Person> .
  ?person <http://it.dbpedia.org/property/nome> ?name .
}
LIMIT 10
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select+%2a+where+%7B%0D%0A++%3Fperson+a+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2FPerson%3E+.%0D%0A++%3Fperson+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fit.dbpedia.org%2Fproperty%2Fnome%3E+%3Fname+.%0D%0A%7D%0D%0ALIMIT+10&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=0&debug=on)

This query doesn't return anything, so it would be best to debug it before continuing on the the FILTER or COUNT.

After playing with the endpoint for a while, it seems that using REGEX is going to be kind of expensive, as are other string operations.  If you can query for the strings you want directly, you might be better off.  Unfortunately, you'll need to start working with language tags, too.  For instance, here is a query that counts people with the given name or surname `"Leonardo"`.

```
select COUNT(?person) where {
  ?person a dbpedia-owl:Person .
  { ?person foaf:givenName "Leonardo" }
  UNION 
  { ?person foaf:surname "Leonardo" }
}
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select+COUNT%28%3Fperson%29+where+%7B%0D%0A++%3Fperson+a+dbpedia-owl%3APerson+.%0D%0A++%7B+%3Fperson+foaf%3AgivenName+%22Leonardo%22+%7D%0D%0A++UNION+%0D%0A++%7B+%3Fperson+foaf%3Asurname+%22Leonardo%22+%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=0&debug=on)

It returns `0`.  However, if we add (English) language tags to those strings, we get different results (`133`):

```
select COUNT(?person) where {
  ?person a dbpedia-owl:Person .
  { ?person foaf:givenName "Leonardo"@en }
  UNION 
  { ?person foaf:surname "Leonardo"@en }
}
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select+COUNT%28%3Fperson%29+where+%7B%0D%0A++%3Fperson+a+dbpedia-owl%3APerson+.%0D%0A++%7B+%3Fperson+foaf%3AgivenName+%22Leonardo%22%40en+%7D%0D%0A++UNION+%0D%0A++%7B+%3Fperson+foaf%3Asurname+%22Leonardo%22%40en+%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=0&debug=on)

Comment: ok, tnx so much but I still have problem running this new query into SWI-Prolog shell

Comment: Is there an error?  Is the number different than what you expect? … Without more details, it's hard to give any more suggestions…

Comment: ah no okok...I just entered it into the sparql_query swi prolog predicate and work well

Comment: @AndreaNobili Glad to hear it!  There have been lots of questions about [DBpedia](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dbpedia) on StackOverflow lately;  It's nice to see people making use of it!

Comment: I am using it for an universitary exam project that implement a semantic information recognition into text. I am very new in this world and it seems to me very interesting !!!